# Why parallettes have small height?

Tags: gymnastics

I want to build a PVC parallette at home and I noticed that all the parallettes are very small in height( as the diminutive french suffix ette indicates , pretty obvious , I know lol )

My question is : why they have to be low? and if I increased the height of the parallette would that decrease the effectiveness of the the exercises in other words which is more challenging for gymnastic exercises , lower or higher?

Excuse my English as I am not a native speaker.Thanks.

Comment: Define "low height".

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr They're usually 6-12 inches off the ground.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a higher set of parallettes, it will not increase the difficulty. A V sit done 12 inches off of the ground is not more difficult than one done 8 feet off the ground.

What it does do is increase the safety factor, in that if you try to pull through from a V sit into a vertical handstand on the bars, if you fail or lose grip then you do not have very far to fall. However, you do need to consider the stability, so when you make them be sure not to cut the cross member "feet" too short.

Comment: Well, the exercise would be more challenging if you had to _absolutely make sure_ you don't fall, because you're 8 feet above ground. I'm kidding of course, good point with the safety factor.

Answer (score 0):

The small size of parallettes is a combination of convenience, stability, and sturdiness. Small size makes them easy to store and transport. And the taller you make them, the more you have to build up the base for stability, and build the bars wider to make them sturdy enough to hold your full body weight.